# Tkinter PhotoImage in Juypter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

(fairly new to python)
My code works perfectly when running in Spyder(Python 2.7) (where I wrote it), but I want to put it in Juypter notebook (as I have other work to put alongside it), but it can't seem to find 'MaxShearStress.PNG'.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%gui tk
import Tkinter as tk


class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        root.title("Max Shear Stress")
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(
            frame, text="CONTINUE TO DATA INPUT", command=frame.quit
            )
        self.button.pack(side='left')

        self.s_block = tk.Button(frame, text="SHOW STRESS BLOCK DIAGRAM",     command=self.stress_b)
        self.s_block.pack(side='left')

    def stress_b(self):
        #root.title("Max Shear Stress")
        img = tk.PhotoImage(file= "MaxShearStress.PNG")
        c = tk.Canvas(width = 600, height = 400)
        c.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
        c.create_image(10, 10, image=img, anchor='nw')
        root.mainloop()

root = tk.Tk()

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

this is the error it comes up with in juypter:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/christopherfrancis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py",     line 1542, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-1-75a48478dca7>", line 27, in stress_b
    img = tk.PhotoImage(file= "MaxShearStress.PNG")
  File "/Users/christopherfrancis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py",     line 3372, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/Users/christopherfrancis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py",    line 3326, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
TclError: couldn't open "MaxShearStress.PNG": no such file or directory
```

But I have saved it in the same folder as my Python coding?

Comment: ah thank you, I tried it as a .gif but that didn't work either do you know how i can resolve this?

Comment: Sorry, I just deleted my comment. Are you sure your image is in the same folder(working directory) with your .py file?

Comment: I was wrong, wasn't in same folder, Thank you so much!